# How do I kill user applications from an IRQ handler?

Tags: linux-kernel, irq

I am working on an embedded Linux system, and I need to shut the system down when a particular IRQ handler runs. I don't have a lot of time (tens of milliseconds). I was using emergency_restart(), but I now need to perform some work (writing shutdown-related info to flash) that cannot be done from an interrupt context because the flash driver will not support it.

Can anyone recommend a good way to accomplish this? I would love to properly kill my user-space applications by sending them a signal so that they can do the flash write. How do I do this? I suppose, as an alternative, I could have a high priority process that sits, waiting on a semaphore that my interrupt generates... What are my options? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what signals are for.  If one of the existing signals don't make sense (see `man 7 signal`), use one of the user definable signals:

```
#define SIGUSR1         10      /* User-defined signal 1 (POSIX).  */
#define SIGUSR2         12      /* User-defined signal 2 (POSIX).  */
```